# What dependencies do I exactly need for second level caching in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, caching

I've read a few articles.
One - says that these dependencies are needed:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Another only this one:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
<version>5.2.2.Final</version>
```

The question is, why do I need an API for caching in the first example? Doesn't hibernate have it's own? And why is spring-boot-starter-cache not needed in the second example?

These are two articles I am referring to.

[First example](https://springframework.guru/using-ehcache-3-in-spring-boot/)

[Second one](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache)

Comment: In the first example you linked, the cache is used to cache a result generated by a service-bean. In the second example you linked, the cache is used to cache database-results. Those are different use-cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these tutorials shows different approaches to caching.

1. First is for implementing Cache on Spring level. By doing this you can implement your cache on some specific methods in your Spring application or calls to other APIs. That's why you need `spring-boot-starter-cache` and `cache-api` - `spring-boot-starter-cache` because of using it with Spring, `cache-api` because your cache won't use hibernate api.
2. Second is for implementing Cache on Hibernate level. Here your cache will be used during calls to DB - you can't use it for caching some methods, call to other API's and so on. That's why you don't need `spring-boot-starter-cache` - your code simply won't use those.

If you want to just cache your calls to DB then go with second approach. If you are trying to cache executions of your methods that can (but don't need to) use DB then go with first approach.